# Angular routing under wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WordPress site where one of the pages that WordPress serve is an SPA based on AngularJS. The Angular-app uses `html5mode` so that I can browse to `http://localhost/79133/71` and I'm still showing index.html. Now I want to deploy this to my WordPress site so that one of the pages under WordPress (the main page) is my SPA. However, if I browse to `http://example.com/79133/71` WordPress will try to find the page with the permalink `79133/71` and won't understand that the main page should be served. How can i configure WordPress so that these new "routes" will be pointing to the first page?

Comment: Did you ever solve this, as I have the same question? http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/193479/redirect-sub-pages-to-parent-without-changing-url

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on WordPress, but in order to get html5mode to work in angular:

1. Any route starting with `/your_spa` needs to serve the main page (`index.html`) of your app.
2. You must ensure that any resources referenced in your spa (for example, `/assets/themes/theme.css`) needs to point to the correct location, even if your location url is `your_spa/your/spa/page`. This means no relative paths unless you use the [base tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base).

[Here's a tutorial](https://ruslanbes.com/devblog/2013/04/03/wordpress-routing-explained/) on how to configure the router in wordpress. I don't use wordpress so I'm sorry that I

It seems like a lot of trouble, and I would just use the default hash routes if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same basic issue, and solved it. Your situation is slightly different but I think you need something like:

```
function spa_rewrite() {
  add_rewrite_rule('79133/71', '/', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'spa_rewrite');
```

In practise you'll need to use some regex to make this more flexible